# If my class is Category, Am I supposed to name my SQL table "categorys" and not "categories"?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Any simpler way to not depend on Laravel's sql table naming convention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Model` you can override the table it's going to use. Just add a protected property:

```
class Category extends Model {
    protected $table = 'categories123123'; //For example =D
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`categories`, it works it out using [Doctrine's Inflector class](https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php)!

Comment: Wow. Laravel's way ahead of what I can imagine.